# Angular 2 TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of null error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I have angular 2 project, after updating @angular/cli ,webpack and typescript version I get this error, confusing side is that I only get error in this angular 2 project, another one works perfectly fine. I share error and package.json below. I have updated angular cli globally and locally. Is there any problem with versions or?

```
\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:329
                                    if(_this.profile) {
                                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of null
```

package.json

```
{
"name": "crm-ca",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"angular-cli": {},
"scripts": {
  "start": "ng serve",
  "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
  "test": "ng test",
  "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
  "e2e": "protractor"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
  "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
  "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.5",
  "angular2-text-mask": "^2.1.0",
  "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.3",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
  "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
  "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
  "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.32",
  "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
  "@types/jquery": "^2.0.40",
  "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
  "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
  "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
  "karma": "1.2.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
  "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
  "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
  "protractor": "~4.0.13",
  "ts-node": "1.2.1",
  "tslint": "^4.0.2",
  "typescript": "^2.2.2",
  "webpack": "^2.2.0",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.1.0-beta.9"
 }
}
```

Comment: Did you try deleting node_modules folder and executing *npm install* again?

Comment: about 10 times yesterday)

Comment: Why do you need webpack? Try remove it from package.json, angular-cli uses its own version

Comment: I removed it and deleted node_modules and npm install again, now i get this error:
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined at Promise.resolve.then.then.then

Comment: What is the use of "angular-cli": {},
 in package.json?Can you try removing that?Also please post screenshot of your error instead of pasting the text?

Comment: Hi, having the same error... have you managed to solve?

Comment: Solved it by downgrading cli version @Raichel

Comment: to which version you downgraded?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend removing `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server` from your `package.json`. `angular-cli` uses its own version of `webpack` which is clashing with what's in your `package.json`. I had this issue and that's the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6417) and it worked for me:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev webpack
sudo rm -R node_modules
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey remove the `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server` from your `package.json` and run the `npm uninstall --save-dev webpack` this should handle your situation.